# SQL Stored Procedure Send mail with attachement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, email-attachments, sp-send-dbmail

i have a stored procedure that sends an email with an attachment, one of the developers decided to drop the lookup table with the file paths in, I've recreated the table but cant remember how the string needs to be for the file path and name to be picked up.

I've tried N'C:\Filename.xls' AND N'\\PCName\temp\filename.xls' and a few other variations but keep getting "Attachment file N'C:\Filename.xls' is invalid".

I've assigned the relevant file permissions so that there are no access restrictions on the folder or file that the file is stored in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! The SQL instance is set up to use the built in SA account for authentication by default which has no access to local drives!! what a pain!!